# How to find out the length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

```
std::string array[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

How do I find out the length of the `array` in code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::begin` and `std::end`, if you have C++11 support.:

```
int len = std::end(array)-std::begin(array); 
// or std::distance(std::begin(array, std::end(array));
```

Alternatively, you write your own template function:

```
template< class T, size_t N >
size_t size( const T (&)[N] )
{
  return N;
}

size_t len = size(array);
```

This would work in C++03. If you were to use it in C++11, it would be worth making it a `constexpr`.

Comment: Or `std::extent<decltype(array)>::value`.

Comment: @sftrabbit I hadn't even thought of that one. Nice!

Comment: @sftrabbit Make **that** an answer and get my +1

Comment: Your `len` is missing a `constexpr` :)

Comment: @DanielFrey good point, but I wanted to provide a C++03 option. I will add a note about that.

Comment: I'd also argue that the function should be named `size`, rather than `len`, to relate it to the member functions of the containers in the same way `begin()` and `end()` were.

Comment: @JamesKanze You're right, that is what I usually call it. I have been doing too much python this week.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `sizeof()`-operator like in

```
int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

or better, use `std::vector` because it offers `std::vector::size()`.

```
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) is the doc. Consider the range-based example.

Comment: Is it possible to define an `std::vector` with initializaiton (like in my example with ordinary array)?

Comment: C++11 offeres initializers. Otherwise you can create an array as you did and assign it to the std::vector. Ill post the doc in a minute

Comment: This C level expression should not be recommended without explaining [its type unsafety and how that can be remedied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/7439261#7439261).

Answer (score 3):

C++11 provides [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) which gives you the number of elements along the `N`th dimension of an array. By default, `N` is 0, so it gives you the length of the array:

```
std::extent<decltype(array)>::value
```

Comment: Does it do all the calculations at compile time (i.e. after compilation it's just a number, needing no extra calculations)?

Comment: @NPS: yes, you can see that from the fact that it's a type

Comment: Any way to make it short (like macro but I'd rather not use macros)?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

Comment: I knew this one but I thought it might not work with `std::string` (due to variable text lengths).

Comment: This C level expression should not be recommended without explaining [its type unsafety and how that can be remedied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/7439261#7439261).

Comment: @NPS `sizeof(std::string)` is always the same ; it does not have anything to do with how many characters are stored in the string