# Concatenating an array size in cout statement

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to output the number of element-objects in my array, but the syntax for that is not the same as it is for Java:

```
    // print list of all messages to the console
void viewSent()
{
    cout << "You have " << sent.size() << " new messages.\n";//Error: left of '.size' must have class/struct,union
    std::cout << "Index      Subject" << '\n';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sent.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << "    : " << sent[i].getSubject() << '\n';
    }
}
```

if the .size doesn't work in C++ syntax, what does?

Comment: "but the syntax for that is not the same as it is for Java." This is unsurprising because C++ is not Java.

Comment: Update this code to show the definition of `sent`

Answer (score 4):

The C++ equivalent of a Java array is `std::vector`. `sent.size()` is the correct way to get the size.

You didn't post your definition of `sent` but it should be `std::vector<YourObject> sent;`, perhaps with initial size and/or values also specified.

I'm guessing you tried to use a C-style array -- don't do that, C-style arrays have strange syntax and behaviour for historical reasons and there is really no need to use them ever in C++.

Comment: I know vectors are better, but right now, I need the C-style array version of .size() Anybody know?

Comment: @SamJava_The_Hut So it is not a vector? Can you post your definition of `sent`?

Comment: There is no C-style array version of `size()`. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861115/how-to-find-out-the-length-of-an-array) for some ideas.

Comment: Deqing, the gory details of the sent definition can be found in the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071083/expression-must-have-class-type-with-array-concatination

Answer (score 0):

If your array is a C-Array, you can loop through it like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(sent) / sizeof(TYPE)); ++i)
```

... where TYPE is the underlying type of the array.

For example, if sent is defined as:

```
int sent[];
```

... then TYPE would be `int`, like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(sent) / sizeof(int)); ++i)
```

A C-Array is not an object. So it has no members or methods and you cannot use the member operator with it. The `sizeof` operator is used to find the size of a fundamental type, in bytes. `sizeof` returns an integer value of type `size_t`.